# Making ECDF plot in GGplot using double aes

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, ecdf

I kind of stuck how to obtain ECDF (line and point combined together) plot using more than 1 aes (could be color, linetype for `geom_line` or shape for `geom_point`).
So, I have this code for example

```
data<-mtcars
  data$cyl<-as.factor(data$cyl)
  data$am<-as.factor(data$am)

    ggplot(data,aes(qsec))+
        geom_line(stat = "ecdf",aes(linetype=cyl))+
        geom_point(stat="ecdf",size=2,aes(shape=cyl))+
        labs(x="sample")+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
              text = element_text(size = 11, family = "serif"))+
        scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(sprintf("%1.0f", x*100),"%"))+
        scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                      labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))
        )
```

It is nicely formed ECDF plots by cyl type

[image].

But, then I wanted to mark some points based on `am` category, with adding color=am within the aes of `geom_point`, then the results were seemingly randomly scattered

[image].

I guess, it is because I used ECDF so, it created new individual cumulative calculations based on new category I've created. Could anybody help me out here? thanks

Comment: You want a different mapping for the stat and for the geom. I'm not sure that's possible. I'd calculate the statistics outside ggplot2.

Comment: Thanks Roland... I appreciate it... So I want the normal ecdf plot as the first picture, but the geom_point shows different color by another aes... In this case 'am'

Comment: I had understood that already. I just explained what that means for ggplot2.

Comment: I don't know if what you are tying to achieve is possible, because the way I understand this, the ECDF as you calculated it ignores the "am" category as it is calculated based on the values of qsec irrespective of the am (automatic or manual) variable. 
If you reintroduce "am" in the aes, then you are, as you said, recalculating based on the categorical variable. So the points will not be on the lines which are calculated with all the values of qsec. 
If you want the lines to match the points you need to add the color in the line aes as well.

Answer (score 2):

The various stats that you can use in ggplot are helpful when you want to carry out a common simple statistical transformation, but often if you're trying to do something unusual as you are doing here (show ecdfs split by one group and colors split by another group), they can make it more difficult to achieve your goal than just passing the data you actually want to plot:

```r
data <- mtcars
  data$cyl  <- as.factor(data$cyl)
  data$am   <- as.factor(data$am)
  data$ecdf <- numeric(nrow(data))
  
data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, data$cyl), function(x) {
  x$ecdf <- ecdf(x$qsec)(x$qsec); 
  x[order(x$ecdf),]
  }))
 
ggplot(data, aes(qsec, ecdf)) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype = cyl)) +
    geom_point(size = 2, aes(shape = cyl, colour = am)) +
    labs(x = "sample") +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          text = element_text(size = 11, family = "serif")) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(sprintf("%1.0f", x*100), "%")) +
    scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't thank you enough... I managed to achieve what I want! Great! But I need more time to comprehend `do.call` and stuff... many thanks!